# Add Trendline to ASP.Net Chart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, data-visualization, mschart, asp.net-charts

Is there a way to an ASP.Net Chart Control (like in Excel)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good article on doing that on the 4Guys from Rolla site:

"Using Microsoft's Chart Controls In An ASP.NET Application: Adding Statistical Formulas"

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131236/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111809-1.aspx